# Mocking file-like gzipped csv for boto3's StreamingBody

Tags: python, boto3, python-unittest, botocore

My real S3 helper does the following:

```
def read_gzipped_csv_from_s3(self, key):
    return self.bucket.Object(key).get()

obj = S3Helper().read_gzipped_csv_from_s3(key)
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], compression='gzip')
```

I need to mock `read_gzipped_csv_from_s3()` method for unit tests. The problem is that the response should be a gzipped CSV which I must construct from a string because I cannot store anything as tests are running in a Gitlab's pipeline.

So I have some csv as a string:

```
CSV_DATA = """
name,value,control
ABC,1.0,1
DEF,2.0,0
GHI,3.0,-1
"""
```

Then I have some example code for using a regular CSV file to mock botocore.response.StreamingBody:

```
body_encoded = open('accounts.csv').read().encode()
mock_stream = StreamingBody(io.BytesIO(body_encoded), len(body_encoded))
```

but I can't figure out how to create gzipped CSV in memory: there's the beginning I've found somewhere:

```
import gzip

buffer = BytesIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer, mode='wb') as compressed:
    with TextIOWrapper(compressed, encoding='utf-8') as wrapper:
        <can't figure out what's here>
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Tried tons of other snippets from SO and modified them but no luck. What I expect: gzipped CSV file-like object to pass to StreamingBody

Comment: I don't understand why I don't see `import` [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) in your code. How were you planning to create an object with the proper behavior otherwise?

Comment: @J_H, I omitted this code previously because I was totally unsure that it's even close to what I need. Now I've restored it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.write()` to write the data into the `BytesIO` object. You also need `.seek()` to reset the file position to the beginning before you can read it.

```
import gzip
from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper

buffer = BytesIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer, mode='wb') as compressed:
    with TextIOWrapper(compressed, encoding='utf-8') as wrapper:
        wrapper.write(CSV_DATA)
buffer.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(buffer, compression='gzip')
```

Comment: Sorry for missing that @nick-odell, I did that, thank you